# Installing SRA-SiliconValley Jalangi on Windows7 fails

Tags: javascript, python, windows, node.js, jalangi

I am trying to install automated test case generator for Javascipt called SRA-SiliconValley/jalangi
https://github.com/SRA-SiliconValley/jalangi

I am using Python 2.7
node.js v0.10.26
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010,
Installed Version: WD Express,
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

When I attempt to run

```
python ./scripts/install.py
```

it fails with the following message:

[image]

full install log:

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.14.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.14.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opts
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/html5-entities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/opts
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opts/-/opts-1.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/html5-entities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/html5-entities/-/html5-entities-0.5.1.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/opts/-/opts-1.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/html5-entities/-/html5-entities-0.5.1.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom/-/jsdom-0.10.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom/-/jsdom-0.10.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nwmatcher
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/-/htmlparser2-3.7.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.6.0.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom/-/cssom-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle/-/cssstyle-0.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nwmatcher
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nwmatcher/-/nwmatcher-1.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.34.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser2/-/htmlparser2-3.7.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.6.0.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify/-/contextify-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.34.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle/-/cssstyle-0.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nwmatcher/-/nwmatcher-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify/-/contextify-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom/-/cssom-0.3.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domutils
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/domelementtype/-/domelementtype-1.1.1.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domutils
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.4.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/bindings/-/bindings-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/entities
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/entities/-/entities-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.12
.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domutils/-/domutils-1.4.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/bindings/-/bindings-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/forever-agent/-/forever-agent-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/entities/-/entities-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.6.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/form-data/-/form-data-0.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/http-signature/-/http-signature-0.10.0.t
gz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe/-/json-stringify-saf
e-5.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/oauth-sign/-/oauth-sign-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/tunnel-agent/-/tunnel-agent-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/forever-agent/-/forever-agent-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/form-data/-/form-data-0.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe/-/json-stringify-saf
e-5.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/domelementtype/-/domelementtype-1.1.1.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/http-signature/-/http-signature-0.10.0.t
gz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/aws-sign2/-/aws-sign2-0.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/oauth-sign/-/oauth-sign-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/aws-sign2/-/aws-sign2-0.5.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.12
.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/isarray/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/isarray/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.    npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.25-
1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-0.12.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.25-
1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-0.12.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-0.8.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-0.8.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/combined-stream/-/combined-stream-0.0.4.
tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.1.11.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-0.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/ctype/-/ctype-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/combined-stream/-/combined-stream-0.0.4.
tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/cryptiles/-/cryptiles-0.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.2.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-0.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.1.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/ctype/-/ctype-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/sntp/-/sntp-0.2.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/cryptiles/-/cryptiles-0.2.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.2.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-0.4.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/sntp/-/sntp-0.2.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-0.4.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.    npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.    npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tg
z

> execSync@1.0.1-pre install     C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jal
angi-master\node_modules\execSync
> node-    gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node_modules\exec
Sync>node "        C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\    npm\bin\node-    gyp-bin\\..\..\node
_modules\node-    gyp\bin\node-    gyp.js" rebuild
    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32
.Targets(147,5): error : Required file "" is missing. [    C:\Users\Administrator\D
ownloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node_modules\execSync\build\shell.vcxpro
j]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (        C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-    gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "    C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\    npm\\node_modu
les\\node-    gyp\\bin\\node-    gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd     C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node
_modules\execSync
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-    gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok

> contextify@0.1.7 install     C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalan
gi-master\node_modules\rewriting-proxy\node_modules\html5\node_modules\jsdom\nod
e_modules\contextify
> node-    gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node_modules\rewr
iting-proxy\node_modules\html5\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>node "
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\    npm\bin\node-    gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\no
de-    gyp\bin\node-    gyp.js" rebuild

    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32
.Targets(147,5): error : Required file "" is missing. [    C:\Users\Administrator\D
ownloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node_modules\rewriting-proxy\node_module
s\html5\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (        C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-    gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "    C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\    npm\\node_modu
les\\node-    gyp\\bin\\node-    gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd     C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\node
_modules\rewriting-proxy\node_modules\html5\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\cont
extify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-    gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! execSync@1.0.1-pre install: `node-    gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the execSync@1.0.1-pre install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the execSync package,
npm ERR! not with     npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-    gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!         npm owner ls execSync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "    C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "    C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\    npm\\bin\\    npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd     C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR!     npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing jsdom@0.10.5
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!         C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master\    npm-
debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm install failed

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jalangi-master\jalangi-master>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there is a space in the file path. e.g., *C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules*. You might want to try it on Mac OS or Linux.
You can also post an issue to the [github repository](https://github.com/SRA-SiliconValley/jalangi/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).

Comment: Could be, is there a way of making it handle the spaces?

Comment: One possible reason is that Jalangi invokes command line in console to accomplish some basic task, having a space in the file path simply makes the path being parsed as a file path and a option, so wrapping the file path inside Jalangi with "" probably can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do some work in jalangi on my own as well, but it hasn't been a easy ride. I spent about 3 weeks trying to install jalangi on windows. my problem was with cvc3, that is with the libgmp library. it said that I needed to install it, although it was already installed on my PC. after that i switched to Ubuntu and installed the whole thing within 10 minutes... so my advice is forget about installing it on windows and switch to ubuntu, over a virtual machine or by dual booting, whatever.it is quite easy to install using the instructions on github: https://github.com/SRA-SiliconValley/jalangi

but after installing it I hit another wall. It is not that easy to figure out how to use it, or how to set it up with Tizen IDE like in the demo video (the video can be found in jalangi-html-test/paper ,but not in jalangi-master).

So if anyone has some experience with using this or setting it up, I'd be very grateful. Also, I'd be happy to share my experience on this, because this is still a relatively young project and there is still not much out there on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I am working as a contractor at the moment, and do not have 'luxury' of choosing my OS. I need to make it work on Widows or get another tool that generates JS test cases.

Comment: then maybe one more thing that I could suggest, it worked just partially for me. I modified the install.py file and tried to correct error by error. I noticed that some URL paths were not entirely correct. but, as said, it didn't work completely at the end